# how to use a project source code in another app module

Tags: java, android, android-studio, module, dependencies

I'm developing an application which includes multiple subproject. for example, it contains a calendar, a calculator and weather. for saving time I want to use source codes from Github. I found a calendar source in GitHub and import that as module and then I want to open calender's Mainactivity in a mainapp activity.
I tried to add a dependency from the main module to the calendar module but the android studio doesn't allow this function.
I will be grateful for any answer that helps me to use the calendar source code in my main project.

Answer (score 2):

I think [jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) library is what you are looking for.
You can import github projects as a dependency in your build.gradle file (like maven dependencies).

Note that you cant edit the github project directly in your project.

Comment: thanks,great answer,but not work for my case. 
https://github.com/ebraminio/DroidPersianCalendar                                           
 is there any other solution to create library from source code?